# Как тестировать API с третьей стороны?

Tags: api, юнит-тесты, тестирование, backend, задание-на-собеседовании

На собеседовании на позицию Junior QA задали такой вопрос. Как правильно на него ответить? Спасибо

Comment: Ну, смотря что за АПИ и что тестируем.

Comment: Например, веб-сервер с архитектурой микросервисов (с учётом REST API)

Comment: Недавно отвечал на похожий вопрос здесь - https://t.me/qa_pro/414, может поможет :)

Answer (score 1):

Я не junior QA, и даже не QA, но расскажу, как я бы это делал. Рассмотрим для начала, что это http api (один из самых типичных случаев).

Если есть API, то первым делом нужно попросить документацию на него. Также спросил, нет ли у них [swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-inspector/) или чего то подобного. Если есть - супер, можно уже начать ручное тестирование - читаем документацию и пробуем. Потом составляем план тестирования. Не забываем протестировать "разнообразные варианты".

Если же swagger нет, тогда можно написать ручками. Тут ничего сложного нет и зависит только от Ваших возможностей и того, что есть в компании. Возможно, у них уже есть что то для такого тестирования (хороший вариант ответа  - "пойду спрошу тим/тех лида, может кто то уже делал подобное").

Если уже нужно писать ручками, то тут варианты разнообразные - от curl/wget  в консоли и [питона](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itrgje2oqqU) до [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

Ещё один вариант - попросить программистов в программе сделать возможность вызывать это апи в контексте приложения (какое-то отладочное меню).

Если же это апи другое (например, это библиотека на каком то языке програмирования), то тут вариантов не много - писать тесты на этом языке и планомерно покрывать все варианты. Но это суперширокий вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Размышляя над ответом... Если у нас всего две стороны, или веб-клиент (протестировать можно любыми платформами типа Postman, curl и т.д.), или веб-сервер. Протестировать с третьей стороны можно в среде разработки на localhost с помощью, например, JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создать тестовую точку
2. Написать документацию
3. Дать доступ третей стороне